# Crack the lines

Tags: pattern

Follow this series: 
Can you guess the last two results?

```
OOOOO = 0
LTSSJI = 4
IIIIIIIIII = 0
I90I90O90 = 2
SSSSJ = 5
T180T180T180S270 = ¿?
LZZZZ = ¿?
```

EDITED: Thanks to Deusovi who solved it and also found an error: changed second line to LTSSJI = 4

Comment: There's another error. SSSSJ should be 5. Also, if I've solved it, could you accept my answer?

Comment: This is seriously awesome.

Comment: Marked as accepted. Kudos!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The number represents how many...

> other Tetris pieces you'd need to clear the board. Each string represents tetrominoes being dropped onto a standard 10-wide board; the numbers represent rotations by 90, 180, or 270 degrees. Unfortunately, I seem to have stumbled across a better solution for two of them.

Here's a diagram in Google Sheets:

> [image: gsheet]

So the solution is

> 6 and 5.

Comment: how do you come to this solutions ? I mean, how did you think of tetris ??

Comment: @FernandoNomellini - Tetrominoes are named based on their shape. All of the names showed up, and no other letters did.

Comment: Um... you have LTJSJI in your answer instead of LTSSJI...?

Comment: @jpmc26 Look at the edits on the question; that was the part that was edited because questioner recognized the mistake

Comment: @FernandoNomellini I didn't get it either, till I looked at the legend at the top. Each letter represents a tetris piece, *visio-netically*: ([Tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino))